# What's wrong with my MM/DD/YYYY regex in JENKINS

Tags: regex, date, jenkins, date-format

I need to validate the date format in MM/DD/YYYY. Null is a valid too in my scenario.
This is my regex `[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$ |`

Below image shows the job configuration with my regex

[image: Jenkins config]

ERROR

[image: Job error]

Comment: I'm sure you know, `[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$` allows for invalid dates, eg: `99/99/0000`

Comment: yeah you are correct. I am validating the actual date in a shell. So for this parameter I just want to check for d{2}/d{2}/d{4} pattern. My given input seems to be correct but not sure why the failure msg is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have space after the $ sign, that's why you input doesn't match.

```
[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$ |
//                    here __^
```

Remove it (`[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$`) and, if you want to accept empty string, add empty string with a group, and add beginning of string anchor:

```
^([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}|)$
```

or, better, make the group optional

```
^([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})?$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/t5Dfat/1)

Answer (score 1):

I modified the original to this:

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec))(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:(?:0?2|(?:Feb))(\/|-|\.)(?:29)\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

[Test the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/vL5mV7/1)

Comment: This seems to be working. But I would just need mm/dd/yyyy. I am verifying given date in another place. For for the regex any digits in this d{2}/d{2}/d{4} pattern should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the initial validation with

```
^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$
```

I have added `^` to indicate the start of the string and I have removed `|` (it is union operator, OR) from the end of your original regex. I tested it [here](https://regex101.com/).